# How to change the legend bar in latex?

Tags: pgfplots

I am using tikzpicture to draw the chart in latex. However, the legend appears double rectangular. Could I change the legend to one rectangular. Thanks

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure} 
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            xlabel = X,
            xmin = 0.0,
            xmax = 5,
            ymin = 0.5,
            ymax = 6.0,
            axis x line* = bottom,
            axis y line* = left,
            ylabel= Y,
            ymajorgrids = true,
            xticklabels = \empty,
            extra x ticks = {1,2,3,4, 5},
            extra x tick labels = {1,2,3,4,5},
            ylabel near ticks,
            legend style={draw=darkgray!60!black,fill=white,align=left,legend pos= north west,legend columns=-1}
            ]           
            \addplot [red!20!black,fill=red!80!white] coordinates {
                (1,1)
                (2,2)
                (3,4)
                (4,3)               
            };
            \addlegendentry{A};         
        \end{axis} 
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Test}  
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: See p 262 of the manual. You have to redefine the legend image, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redefine the `legend image` as

```
    legend image code/.code={
        \draw [/tikz/.cd,bar width=3pt,yshift=-0.2em,bar shift=0pt]
        plot coordinates {(0cm,0.8em)};
    },
```

which yields:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure} 
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            xlabel = X,
            xmin = 0.0,
            xmax = 5,
            ymin = 0.5,
            ymax = 6.0,
            axis x line* = bottom,
            axis y line* = left,
            ylabel= Y,
            ymajorgrids = true,
            xticklabels = \empty,
            extra x ticks = {1,2,3,4, 5},
            extra x tick labels = {1,2,3,4,5},
            ylabel near ticks,
            legend image code/.code={
                \draw [/tikz/.cd,bar width=3pt,yshift=-0.2em,bar shift=0pt]
                plot coordinates {(0cm,0.8em)};
            },
            legend style={draw=darkgray!60!black,fill=white,align=left,legend pos= north west,legend columns=-1}
            ]           
            \addplot [red!20!black,fill=red!80!white] coordinates {
                (1,1)
                (2,2)
                (3,4)
                (4,3)               
            };
            \addlegendentry{A};         
        \end{axis} 
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Test}  
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! How to add margin/space between two legends. I tried to add one more `B` but they (A and B) are too close

Comment: @Jame: That is a different question and needs its own [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301).